# dual booting ubuntu 14.04.03 LTS along side with my windows 7, but windows doesn't LOAD!

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.03 LTS along side with my windows 7, it's all OK. If I want to access Ubuntu but,on the other hand, when I try to boot windows it gets stuck in that user friendly windows icon("Starting Windows..."), and it "loads/starts windows forever". The only odd thing that I might have done was to update my Ubuntu after installing it.

I NEED HELP I GOT THINGS TO WORK ON IN MY WINDOWS, I'm so worried I damaged windows in some way!

Command `sudo parted -l`:

```
Number    start    end     size    type    file system    signals;
1         1049kb   106Mb   105Mb   primary  ntfs          boot;
2         106kb    391Gb   391Gb   primary  ntfs;
3         391Gb    975Gb   584Gb   extended               lba;
5         391Gb    954Gb   563Gb   logical  ntfs;
6         954Gb    973Gb   19.3Gb  logical  ext4;
7         973Gb    975Gb   2146Mb  logical  linux-swap(v1);
4         975Gb    1000Gb  25.1Gb  primary  ntfs          diag;
```

I have an update, so, my booting screen refers to 2 booting windows have no idea why, placed in dev/sd1 and dev/sd2.

Also, when i try to run windows in safe mode, it gets stuck in this: aswRvrt.sys , should I get my computer to a shop and pay someone even more intelligible to fix it?

Comment: Probably useful to say that i don't have a Windows 7 installation/repair disk, it came with the pc, and that is all...:(

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `sudo parted -l` command.

Comment: @PedroJorge : What you describe means that there is a problem within your Windows installation ! If it would be a GRUB bootloader problem you would not see  the Windows logo ...

Comment: @Pilot6 i did what you said i guess the result is above, lines separated by ";"

Answer (score 0):

Probably your grub is having an issue. open terminal run following commands.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`

Open boot-repair and repair your bootloader. Windows will start showing after complete the setup.

Comment: That will not fix anything with Windows.

Comment: So, i did that, windows gets stuck in the "starting windows" screen